# How does JTAG flash memory programming work?

Tags: embedded, fpga, spi, flash-memory, jtag

I am currently using Xilinx ZCU106 board, and I am curious about How does JTAG support flash memory programming. I can upload the boot images or hardware logic just by connecting JTAG USB cable to USB connector at the ZCU106 Board, and press the flash button on the host PC. By doing this it looks like the QSPI Flash holds the boot images or hardware logic image and the system initializes itself by using this image. It seems like a magic, and I want to know about the detail.

So far I understood is that I can access JTAG interface via USB cable (thanks to the FTDI chip?), and JTAG boundary-scans the devices connected to it.

However the problem is here, I couldn't find the link between JTAG and QSPI Flash (MT25QU512ABB8ESF-0SIT). I searched several references, including manual of QSPI Flash (MT25QU512ABB8ESF-0SIT, https://media-www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/data-sheet/nor-flash/serial-nor/mt25q/die-rev-b/mt25q_qlkt_u_512_abb_0.pdf) but there seems no port for JTAG (such as TDI, TDO, and TCK), but only SPI.

So the first assumption, I thought on the JTAG chain maybe there is a SPI controller to flash the memory. However I couldn't find any clue on the references that I've read so far that a SPI controller exists on the chain or even a SPI controller that controls the QSPI flash really exists. And the second assumption, I thought PS- ARM Cortex A53- TAP (?) does the magic. PS TAP receives JTAG signal and processes the JTAG command. To be precise, let's say about flash memory programming case, then there is like a JTAG command for write data on the flash memory via SPI.

Among these two, I wonder if there is the answer. One thing for the last, if the second one suppose to be the answer, then the processor (Cortex A53) should implement the functionalities by hardware logic to parse Flash write/erase command signal from JTAG interface and let the SPI controller that the system includes perform the write/erase job? Somewhere I read that the JTAG itself supports writing data on the Flash memory but everything I could find was just TDI, TCK, TDO, TMS, and TRST ports which does not fit in any port of QSPI Flash.

Probably I am confusing a lot of concepts very much, but I want to know about the exact mechanism behind the scene on JTAG flash memory programming.

Comment: That is not a question for this site - suggest https://electronics.stackexchange.com/.  But it is not magic - Boundary Scan provides access to each pin on the device, so the host software can provide the signalling required to program the QSPI, or in some cases it might load code onto the target processor to support programming.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, it will do with the following sequence:

- Send some software to target processor in RAM
- Send data to target processor (in RAM)
- Trigger execute command to store data into the flash memory.

Now the expected data are available in flash memory.

Answer (score 1):

Most/all JTAG debuggers/flashers download a small "flash kernel" into the RAM of the target device, transfer control to that code, and communicate with it using the same JTAG interface. The flash kernel executes the commands received from the debugger, and programs internal/external flash memories through the peripheral registers as normal applications would do.

The same can work with QSPI (or any external boot memory, parallel, NAND, etc...) and many (not all) debuggers support that. The primary use case is programming the integrated flash of microcontrollers.

There is usually no direct connection between JTAG and QSPI (or other memories) apart from the NEXUS interface that allows memory access through JTAG. That can be used to program the QSPI peripheral, or in case of a parallel boot flash, the flash directly through the EBI. In theory that could be used for programming any memories, but it would be very slow. An even slower solution is using the boundary scan feature and toggling pins one by one to control the QSPI communication. I did that with a parallel boot flash. It worked but was VERY slow. Professional debuggers use flash kernels.

If your debugger is not capable of QSPI programming, and you're not committed to developing debuggers and flash kernels, I'd recommend that you should create a small application that executes from RAM and programs the flash for you. The data to be programmed can be bundled with the image, or you can even create a full-fledged bootloader that accepts the data through some communication interface.